# Storing a class vector in R

Tags: r, class

I am reading a file to get an idea of the column classes. I would like to store this information in a file for later use with colClasses = classes

```
temp <- read.delim("data.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "|", quote = "", row.names = NULL)

classes <- sapply(temp, class)
```

What file type does "classes" need to be stored in?

Comment: This is very confusing. Why would the file type you use on disk make any difference at all?

Comment: To be more precise, you could store it in literally any file format you wished, as long as you have the ability to read/write that format from R in a way that you get a character vector back. I mean, if you wanted to encode that information in a PNG, you could probably make that work. (But God help you if you do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to save a single object, I would probably use RDS format:

```
saveRDS(classes, file="columnClasses.RDS")
```

and bring it back using `readRDS()`:

```
classes <- readRDS("columnClasses.RDS")
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot. I tried saving it using write.table or write.csv, none of them made any sense.